# Can't boot past login screen

Tags: boot, login

I'm new to Ubuntu. I just installed 12.10 last night and was installing some applications.  I was working on installing wine. When I entered a command from online trying to figure it out the command ended with `purge wine*` because I had installed a wine package and it wouldn't boot. I figured I could delete it.

It started deleting all my applications on my system so I cancelled it by the time I realized. Now when I try to login, it allows me to login and just boots to a blank screen. I can get to the terminal from the login and I tried to use the command: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh -a` but it didn't help.

Is there another idea I can try before I delete the partition and reinstall?

Comment: I ended up re-installing from scratch. I couldn't solve the issue any other way. hope not to make a mistake again

Answer (score 2):

If you have a network connection, you can always try something like `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` (I'm not sure what exactly was the command you ran).

Even then it's not guaranteed this would work 100%, so just in case be prepared to re-install everything from scratch. You learn more the hard way though...

Comment: I can't get an internet connection. I tried that command already and it didn't work for me. The command I ran was to delete wine from my system so that I could reinstall it. From what I read, because of the asterisk it deleted every file with wine in it or related to it. Pretty much screwed me over. You're right though, you learn from mistakes.